# Correct use of jQuery DOM ready and self invoking function

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the correct method to combine jQuery DOM ready and a self invoking function? I see multiple ways to do this across the web, but what method is recommended?

For example, you can put DOM ready in your self invoking function

```
var app = (function($){

    // other stuff here

    init = function () {

    };

    $(function(){
        // DOM Ready stuff here
    });

    return {
        init: init
    }

})(jQuery);

app.init();
```

Or outside like this

```
var app = (function(){

    // other stuff here

    init = function () {

    };

    return {
        init: init
    }

})();

$(function(){
    // DOM Ready stuff here
});

app.init();
```

Or not use DOM ready at all? If i'm correct, this way there is a change that the DOM isn't ready yet:

```
var app = (function($){

    var someElement = $("#foo"); // dom not ready?

    init = function () {

    };

    return {
        init: init
    }

})(jQuery);

app.init();
```

Comment: First one is the best. It is safe and you can call page related functions. You can have a look at source code of this site http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic_admin/. It contains best practices for you

Comment: to me second one is better, just one exception you should call your `app.init();` in doc ready handler.

Comment: because order of execution happens jQuery loads at above all then your anonymous function then you can use your dom ready handler to execute the methods inside of it.

Comment: @Jai That makes sense, but how about global vars, won't using that method increase the chance of ending up with global vars? If you put everything inside the self invoking function you prevent this from happening at all.

Comment: @koningdavid then you can use it two ways first your anonymous function which holds the init method and to save your `$` alias you can either use another anonymous function for using `$` as jQuery or instead you can also try this `jQuery(function($){.....});` to get the `$` as an alias for jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct in saying that without DOM Ready, you might not be able to access some of the Page Elements. Although it depends on were you load your script. If you put it at the bottom before the closing body tag, you will not need the ready event to access elements.

(Sidenote: As with the DOM Ready Event Images won't be loaded at this time though. For this you can use $(window).load() for example).

Personally I like the first one most, I would however also put the Dom Ready Code in a seperate function. You actually don't need to call app.init() from the outside right after invoking the function, you can call it form inside. Like so:

```
var app = (function($){

    // Initialisation Functions (Don't forget var)
    var init = function () {
            // init stuff
        },
        domInit = function () {
            // DOM Ready stuff here
        };

    // Function calls
    init();

    $(function(){
        domInit();
    });

    // if you want to call those functions 
    // some time later from outside of app, 
    // return them:
    return {
        init: init,
        domInit: domInit
    }

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Great explanation, thanks! So far I like this method the best, because everything is in the self invoking function. You forgot a comma btw after "init: init"

Answer (score 2):

what i want to state is this:

```
//your jQuery is loaded before this script.

var app = (function(){
    // other stuff here
     var someElement = $("#foo"); //perfectly fine because dom is ready?
     init = function () {

     };
    return {
       init: init
    }
})();

jQuery(function($){  //<----here you can use $ safely
    app.init();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, appreciate your time! I like this method, I'm just gonna wait a little bit longer to see what other people come up with.

Answer (score 0):

Use of DOM ready totally depends upon your need, if you want to access DOM elements then you should use DOM ready, as if do not use this, then there may be a case when you are accessing any node and applying some function on it but that DOM element is not yet generated.

Use of self invoking anonymous function is to restrict the scope of code, to make it secure and less global and to create any singleton object.

Its similar to creating the function and then calling it. The only difference is these functions do not have any name, so these cannot be accessed/called for anywhere else(since they have no name).

So it is totally your wish, as how you organise your code.

For your code, first approach is best.

Comment: Your first approach has one more benefit that inside your code you can use '$' operator safely.